# Check if an int is between two items in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Alright, so I'm working on a leveling system in java. I have this from my previous question for defining the level "exp" requirements:

```
    int[] levels = new int[100];
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        levels[i] = (int) (levels[i-1] * 1.1);
    }
```

Now, my question is how would I determine if an exp level is between two different integers in the array, and then return the lower of the two? I've found something *close*, but not quite what I'm looking for [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-fixed-point-in-a-given-array/) where it says binary search. Once I find which value the exp falls between I'll be able to determine a user's level. Or, if anyone else has a better idea, please don't hesitate to mention it. Please excuse my possible nooby mistakes, I'm new to Java. Thanks in advance to any answers.

Solved, thanks for all the wonderful answers.

Comment: "I've found something close, but not quite what I'm looking for" Why is this not quite what you're looking for? Seems exactly what you need.

Comment: What keeps you from just storing the level separately?

Comment: @peter.petrov - That locates the index of a fixed point in an array (a position `i` such that `array[i] == i`). That's not at all what OP needs, and I don't know why OP said it was "something close".

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Thanks for bringing it to my attention that I hadn't accepted an answer, I forgot to do that. As for upvoting, I don't know if you're aware or oblivious to the fact, but one cannot upvote a post unless they already have 10 reputation, which is hard to obtain when people downvote you for not having upvoted others.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Edit it in what way? Or do you mean it has to be editted for one's opinion to change? I'm new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a general sorted array of numbers, binary search is the way to go, which is O(log n).  But because there is a mathematical relationship between the numbers (each number is 1.1 times the previous one), take advantage of that fact.  You're looking for the maximum exponent `level` such that

```
levels[0] * Math.pow(1.1, level) <= exp
```

Solving for level,

```
level = log{base 1.1}(exp / levels[0])
```

Taking advantage of the fact that log<sub>a</sub>(b) = ln(b) / ln(a)...

```
int level = (int) Math.log(exp/levels[0]) / Math.log(1.1);
```

Because of the mathematical relationship, you just need this calculation, and no searching, so it's O(1).

```
double base = 1;
double factor = 1.1;

for (double score : Arrays.asList(1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 8.6, 9.46))
{
   int level = (int) (Math.log(score / base) / Math.log(factor));
   System.out.println(level);
}
```

Prints

```
0
1
2
22
23
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [built-in binary search method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
int exp = . . .
int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(levels, exp);
if (pos < 0) {
    // no exact match -- change pos to the insertion index
    pos = -pos - 1;
    // Now exp is between levels[pos] and levels[pos - 1]
    // (or less than levels[0] if pos is now 0)
} else {
    // exp is exactly equal to levels[pos]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do binary search here as your array elements seem to be sorted.
This follows from the way you initialize them.
You can also do linear search of course but the former is better.

Comment: Thanks! Could you briefly explain binary search and possibly give me an easily understandable example? I'll do some research either way, but the more the better.

Comment: @EhhChris Explaining binary search would be out of scope for this question; binary search is one of the most common algorithms in existence and you can find reference implementations for pretty much any language pretty much anywhere.

Comment: If you have a phone book sorted by name, and you're looking for Nicholas, you open the book's middle page. Say there you see the name Michael. So now, it makes no sense to search in the 1st part of the book as Michael < Nicholas. So then you search in the 2nd part of the book only, in the exact same way. This is binary search. Binary search cuts the search space in half at each step.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [Arrays Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)?

```
int valueToFind = 100;
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(levels, valueToFind)
```